# No bean named 'errorNotifier' is defined

Tags: spring, spring-roo

I'm trying to setup a bean factory in spring, something which should be really simple to do, but I just can't figure out why it's not working. Spend most of today looking at examples, reading other similar posts on stackOverflow, reading Spring In Action as well as Spring Recipes with no success so far. A second pair of eyes will probably pick up my mistake in no time.

Error Notifier Interface

```
public interface ErrorNotifier {
    public void notifyCopyError(String srcDir, String destDir, String filename);        
}
```

Error Notifier Implementation

```
public class EmailErrorNotifier implements ErrorNotifier {

    private MailSender mailSender;

    /**
     * Blank constructor
     */
    public EmailErrorNotifier() {
    }

    public void setMailSender(MailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyCopyError(String srcDir, String destDir, String filename) {

        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom("system@localhost");
        message.setTo("admin@localhost");
        message.setSubject("Finished Uploading File");
        message.setText("Your upload failed!");

        mailSender.send(message);

    }
}
```

My config in applicationContext.xml

```
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="${email.host}"/>
        <property name="protocol" value="${email.protocol}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${email.port}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${email.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${email.password}"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="errorNotifier" name="errorNotifier"  class="com.bdw.controller.EmailErrorNotifier">           
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"/>
    </bean>
```

And the class in which I test it

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                ApplicationContext.CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX
                + "applicationContext.xml");

        ErrorNotifier notifier =
                context.getBean("errorNotifier", ErrorNotifier.class);
        notifier.notifyCopyError("test", "test", "test");

    }
}
```

I don't get any errors in tomcat or glassfish logs, just this output:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'errorNotifier' is defined     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:527)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1083)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
>     at test.main(test.java:21)

If I change context.getBean parameter to lookup mailSender, I get No bean named 'mailSender'.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd start with the following: crank of Spring log levels and make sure nothing broken on startup, and make sure that the applicationContext is actually on the classpath at execution.

Comment: applicationContext is currently sitting in
/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml

Comment: Hmm, if you put it in /src/main/resources (assuming a Maven project), does it work?

Comment: That fixes it!!
Funny that Spring ROO puts the mail settings in META-INF if it's not working there :-|
How do I make it work in the default location?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's that classpath prefix that's messing with it? Not sure :/

Comment: You mean in web.xml: 

<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    

Going to simlink it for now and move on.
Post your original answer as a reply, then I can accept your solution.

Comment: When applicationContext is directly in resources (simlinked), it works without the  ApplicationContext.CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX prefixed.

Comment: Moved to answer. I think just adding your location to the test code would work, though, and avoid the hoops :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The applicationContext file is likely not on the class path; I'm not sure that the all_URL_prefix will dig past the root level of the filesystem and jars, making the test go wonky. Try moving the config file, or changing the list of locations from which to grab the config file.

Comment: You are brilliant Dave, glad I can learn from the experts here on stackoverflow. ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml") does the trick.
Tried this solution earlier, but assumed the root directory was META-INF, so obviously it didn't work.

Comment: Not brilliant, just been slammed by the same types of errors ;)